# Two different submit buttons html/cgi form

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am trying to have two different submit buttons.  If one submit button is pressed then it goes to one cgi script and if the other is pressed it goes to another.  Right now below is my code but it isn't working as I want it to.  They both only go to the same script regardless of which one is pressed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
keyword = form.getvalue('keyword')
keyset = set(x.strip() for x in open('keywords.txt', 'r'))


print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r'
print '<html>'
print "Set = ", keyset
print '<h1>If your keyword is in the set, use this submission button to retrieve recent tweets</h1>'
print '<form action="results.cgi" method="post">'
print 'Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword">  <br />'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1" />'
print '</html>'

print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r'
print '<html>'
print '<h1>If your desired keyword is not in the set, use this submission button to add it</h1>'
print '<form action="inlist.cgi" method="post">'
print 'Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword">  <br />'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit2" />'
print '</html>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to have the form post to an intermediary script that decides which script to run based on which submit button was clicked.

So if the value for `Submit1` was provided, run script A. If the value for `Submit2` was provided, run script B.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, mind posting an example or something?  Thanks

Comment: I don't really know the language you're using. I just ran across this post and thought I'd give my 2 cents. Did you figure it out? What code did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dispatch script. This also allows fast imports.
Example:

```
...
print '<form action="dispatch.cgi" method="post">'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1" />'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit2" />'
...
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# dispatch.py (or dispatch.cgi)
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if form.getvalue('Submit1'):
    import results  # result.py: imports are precompiled (.pyc) and decent
    result.handle_cgi(form)  #OR: execfile('results.cgi')
else:
    import inlist
    inlist.handle_cgi(form)  #OR: execfile('inlist.cgi')
```

---

```
# results.py (or results.cgi)
import cgi

def handle_cgi(form):
    keyword = form.getvalue('keyword')
    print 'Content-type: text/html'
    print
    print '<HTML>'
    print "Keyword = ", keyword
    #...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handle_cgi(globals().get('form') or  # don't build / read a POST FS twice
               cgi.FieldStorage())
```

---

```
# inlist.py ...
```